# trim sequences and quality in fastq file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, fastq

I have bunch of fastq files in the directory and i want to trim the sequence by 2 nucleotides and quality(if the read has 51 base pairs and ends-with CTG or TTG).

here is what i wrote as shell script but i am getting some errors,need help as i am new to shell scripting

Input:

```
@HWI-ST1072:187:C35YUACXX:7:1101:1609:1983 1:N:0:ACAGTG
NGGAGAAAGAGAGTGTGTTTTTAGGGGGAGATTTTTAAAATGGTTGTTTTG
+
#0<BFFFFFFFFF<BFFFIIFFFFFIIIBFFFFFIIFIIIIIFFBFFFFFF
@HWI-ST1072:187:C35YUACXX:7:1101:1747:1995 1:N:0:ACAGTG
NGGTTGTGGTGGTGGGTATTTGTAGTTTTATTTATTCGGGAGGTTGAGCTG
+
#0<BFFFFFFFFFFIIBFFIIIIIIFIIIFFIIFIIIFIIFIIFFFFIIFF
@HWI-ST1072:187:C35YUACXX:7:1101:9351:2210 1:N:0:ACAGTG
CGGTTTTGTTTTATTTTGTATGATTAGGAGGGTTTTGGAGGTTTAGTTACC
+
BBBFFFFFFFFFFIIIIIFFIIFIIIIIIIIIFFIIFIFIIFFIIIFIIII
@HWI-ST1072:187:C35YUACXX:7:1101:1747:1995 1:N:0:ACAGTG
NGGTTGTGGTGGTGGGTATTTGTAGTTTTATTTAT
+
#0<BFFFFFFFFFFIIBFFIIIIIIFIIIFFIIFI
```

output:

```
@HWI-ST1072:187:C35YUACXX:7:1101:1609:1983 1:N:0:ACAGTG
NGGAGAAAGAGAGTGTGTTTTTAGGGGGAGATTTTTAAAATGGTTGTTT
+
#0<BFFFFFFFFF<BFFFIIFFFFFIIIBFFFFFIIFIIIIIFFBFFFF
@HWI-ST1072:187:C35YUACXX:7:1101:1747:1995 1:N:0:ACAGTG
NGGTTGTGGTGGTGGGTATTTGTAGTTTTATTTATTCGGGAGGTTGAGC
+
#0<BFFFFFFFFFFIIBFFIIIIIIFIIIFFIIFIIIFIIFIIFFFFII
@HWI-ST1072:187:C35YUACXX:7:1101:9351:2210 1:N:0:ACAGTG
CGGTTTTGTTTTATTTTGTATGATTAGGAGGGTTTTGGAGGTTTAGTTACC
+
BBBFFFFFFFFFFIIIIIFFIIFIIIIIIIIIFFIIFIFIIFFIIIFIIII
@HWI-ST1072:187:C35YUACXX:7:1101:1747:1995 1:N:0:ACAGTG
NGGTTGTGGTGGTGGGTATTTGTAGTTTTATTTAT
+
#0<BFFFFFFFFFFIIBFFIIIIIIFIIIFFIIFI
```

script:

```
for sample in *.fastq;do
    name=$(echo ${sample} | sed 's/.fastq//')
    while read line;do
        if [ ${line:0:1} == "@" ] ; then
                head="${line}"
                $echo $head
        elif [ "${head}" ] && [ "${line}" ] ; then
                length=${#line}
                if [ "${length}" = 51 -a "${line}" =~ *CTG|*TTG ] ; then
                        sequence= substr($line,0,49)
                        #echo $sequence
                fi
        elif [ ${line:0:1} == "+" ] ; then
                plus="${line}"
                #echo $plus
        elif [ "${plus}" ] && [ "${line}" ] ; then
                quality= substr($line,0,49)
                #echo $quality
        fi
        print "${head}\n${sequence}\n${plus}\n${quality}" > ${name}_new.fq
   done < $sample
done
```

Comment: I have getting error in creating the substr!is there a way i can split the lines and save in a variable

Comment: shell is an environment from which to call tools. It has programming language constructs to allow you to sequence those calls. awk is the UNIX command to process text files. Therefore, what you have done so far is completely the wrong approach - the way to do this in shell is to write an awk script to parse your text file and then call it from shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't 100% understand what you're doing, but fixed a few things. Try below

```
#!/bin/bash
for sample in *.fastq; do
  name="${sample/.fastq/}"
  while read -r line; do
    if [[ $line == '@'* ]]; then
      head="$line" && echo "$head" >> "${name}_new.fq"
    elif [[ -n $head && ${#line} == 51 && $line =~ (CTG|TTG)$ ]]; then
      sequence="${line:0:49}" && echo "$sequence" >> "${name}_new.fq"
    elif [[ $line == '+'* ]]; then
      plus="$line" && echo "$line" >> "${name}_new.fq"
    else
      quality="$line" && echo "$quality" >> "${name}_new.fq"
    fi
  done < "$sample"
done
```

Example output

```
> cat sample_new.fq

> cat sample.fastq
@HWI-ST1072:187:C35YUACXX:7:1101:1609:1983 1:N:0:ACAGTG
NGGAGAAAGAGAGTGTGTTTTTAGGGGGAGATTTTTAAAATGGTTGTTTTG
+
#0<BFFFFFFFFF<BFFFIIFFFFFIIIBFFFFFIIFIIIIIFFBFFFFFF
@HWI-ST1072:187:C35YUACXX:7:1101:1747:1995 1:N:0:ACAGTG
NGGTTGTGGTGGTGGGTATTTGTAGTTTTATTTATTCGGGAGGTTGAGCTG
+
#0<BFFFFFFFFFFIIBFFIIIIIIFIIIFFIIFIIIFIIFIIFFFFIIFF
@HWI-ST1072:187:C35YUACXX:7:1101:9351:2210 1:N:0:ACAGTG
CGGTTTTGTTTTATTTTGTATGATTAGGAGGGTTTTGGAGGTTTAGTTACC
+
BBBFFFFFFFFFFIIIIIFFIIFIIIIIIIIIFFIIFIFIIFFIIIFIIII
@HWI-ST1072:187:C35YUACXX:7:1101:1747:1995 1:N:0:ACAGTG
NGGTTGTGGTGGTGGGTATTTGTAGTTTTATTTAT
+
#0<BFFFFFFFFFFIIBFFIIIIIIFIIIFFIIFI

> ./abovescript

> cat sample_new.fq
@HWI-ST1072:187:C35YUACXX:7:1101:1609:1983 1:N:0:ACAGTG
NGGAGAAAGAGAGTGTGTTTTTAGGGGGAGATTTTTAAAATGGTTGTTT
+
@HWI-ST1072:187:C35YUACXX:7:1101:1747:1995 1:N:0:ACAGTG
NGGTTGTGGTGGTGGGTATTTGTAGTTTTATTTATTCGGGAGGTTGAGC
+
@HWI-ST1072:187:C35YUACXX:7:1101:9351:2210 1:N:0:ACAGTG
CGGTTTTGTTTTATTTTGTATGATTAGGAGGGTTTTGGAGGTTTAGTTACC
+
BBBFFFFFFFFFFIIIIIFFIIFIIIIIIIIIFFIIFIFIIFFIIIFIIII
@HWI-ST1072:187:C35YUACXX:7:1101:1747:1995 1:N:0:ACAGTG
NGGTTGTGGTGGTGGGTATTTGTAGTTTTATTTAT
+
```

Comment: its removing every 2 nucleotides of the sequence!!! but i want to remove 2 nucleotides only if the sequence endswith CTG or TTG @BroSlow

Comment: @user2243831 I guess I don't really understand. What do you want to do if a line starts with a `#`? e.g. see update where a line that's not 51 characters and matches other params (e.g. a line that starts with `#` is just printed).

Comment: i just want to trim the sequences by 2 nucleotides if they have 2 conditions(length should be 51 and has CTG or TTG at end).there may be some other sequences that are 51 but if they dont have CTG or TTG i dont trim them.# line should also removed according to the conditions @BroSlow

Comment: @user2243831 Try it again. If that's not it you need to update expected output.

Comment: i need just the second line the sequence to modify based on conditions,the 4 line i can print from 0 to 49!do we need substr function @BroSlow

Comment: i will change the input and output @BroSlow

Comment: @user2243831 No `{line:0:49}` already gets 49 character substring from 0 given your conditions.

Comment: now if you see the first 2 sequences has TTG and CTG at its end and they are 51,i need to trim them as you see in output and the other 2 sequences are different one is 51 but dont have ending sequences i need to keep it and last sequence doesn't satisfy both i keep it @BroSlow

Comment: @user2243831 Right ... the above script already does that, and gets exact same output, except with `#` line removed, which I thought you wanted?

Comment: I see your script is trimming every 51 sequence line in file even they dont have the ends TTG or CTG @BroSlow

Comment: @user2243831 Not unless something bizarre is going on in your environment. Show the output you get from above script.

Comment: This is what i am getting for thir line sequence CGGTTTTGTTTTATTTTGTATGATTAGGAGGGTTTTGGAGGTTTAGTTA

Comment: @user2243831 You sure you have the exact script above?

Comment: I am missing the # lines in the output files,i need them

Comment: @HWI-ST1072:187:C35YUACXX:7:1101:1609:1983 1:N:0:ACAGTG
NGGAGAAAGAGAGTGTGTTTTTAGGGGGAGATTTTTAAAATGGTTGTTT
+                                                                                                                 #0<BFFFFFFFFF<BFFFIIFFFFFIIIBFFFFFIIFIIIIIFFBFFFFFF                  i dont see 4 line changes to 49